# Admob integration - invalid traffic

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, admob

I've question about the integration of Admob. On the moment my admob ads are limited because invalid traffic. The ads are not shown for the last month, so it's totally unclear for me why I received now a mail that ads are limited again? I used multiple banners with the same banner id. After checking my implementation of Admob in swift I think the ads will be refreshed after switching between forms (ads are different after switching between forms). I think that could be possibly a reason for the invalid traffic. Could someone take a look into my added code. What's going wrong?

Admob

```
struct AdView: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AdView>) -> GADBannerView{
        
        let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
                       
        //Test advertisement
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

        banner.rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        banner.load(GADRequest())
        return banner
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADBannerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AdView>) {
    
    }
}
```

Function call in different forms

```
 AdView().frame(width: 100, height: 150, alignment: .bottom)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot your specific issue. But, if your `AdView` is created (the `body` is reloaded/recreated) every time you switch Forms, it be a possible reason this is happening. Test that is by putting a `print()` in your `makeUIView()`. If it gets called more than once then that is probably the issue. Solve this by putting it in a `ParentView` that doesn't get reloaded. Also, I am not sure but I don't think you are allowed to share Banners, have one per # location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your test by putting a print() in makeUIView(). I have one parent form that called a sub form. I placed the banner (call) in the parent form as well as the subform. When I checked the output file it looks like the banner in a subform will be refreshed by opening. Could this be the problem that admob will have to many invalid traffic?

Comment: Possibly, if you are calling `.load` too much, share one banner somehow. Don't recreate it. There are many ways to do this. Keep the `.load` call out of a SwiftUI `body`